# Expectation of $\max_{j=1,\dots,M}X_j^2$ with normal distributed $X_j$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

This is my first question here and I have thought about it for a long time. I found following Lemma in a paper:

Consider the independent random variables $X_1,\dots,X_M \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then it holds
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{j=1,\dots,M}X_j^2 \right]\leq 3\log M +1. 
\end{align*}

The proof uses
\begin{align*}
\max_{j=1,\dots,M}X_j^2\leq \sum_{j=1}^MX_j^2\cdot\chi\left(\lvert X_j\rvert>T\right)+T^2  
\end{align*}
for any $T>0$. At the beginning one shows $\mathbb{E}\left[X_j^2\cdot\chi\left(\lvert X_j\rvert>T\right)\right]\leq \left(1+(2\pi)^{-1/2}T\right)e^{-T^2/2}$. The author uses
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[X_j^2\cdot\chi\left(\lvert X_j\rvert>T\right)\right]=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_T^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
I think this is not correct, since the right hand side should be doubled. Although, I tried to follow the proof further but I am not able to fix this mistake.

The question is: Is this a mistake in the proof or am I overseeing something very trivial? And if the proof is wrong, does anyone know a proof or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need the estimate only for large $M$? I find it hard to believe that this (rather rouge) estimate will give the optimal bound for $M=1$. In any case, there is indeed a $2$ missing in the last equation. Are the constants important for the remainder of the paper?

Comment: For $M=1$ the inequality becomes an equality. I made a Monte Carlo simulation for the expected value with $M=1,\dots,10^6$ and the inequality seemed to be correct, even though quite rough. I don't think the constants are important but it would be nice to follow the paper without having to change results building on this and because it seems right to me, I hoped there was an alternative proof I have not found yet.